# Setting cutout value of ng2-chart doughnut

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797862/how-to-set-cutout-on-doughnut-chart-using-ng2-charts)
but I get the following error:
`Type 'keyof ChartTypeRegistry' is not assignable to type '"doughnut"'.`
When I try to implement it.

Looked into the chartConfiguration docs and saw

```
interface ChartTypeRegistry {
 ...
  pie: {
    chartOptions: PieControllerChartOptions;
    datasetOptions: PieControllerDatasetOptions;
    defaultDataPoint: PieDataPoint;
    metaExtensions: PieMetaExtensions;
    parsedDataType: number;
    scales: keyof CartesianScaleTypeRegistry;
  };
  doughnut: {
    chartOptions: DoughnutControllerChartOptions;
    datasetOptions: DoughnutControllerDatasetOptions;
    defaultDataPoint: DoughnutDataPoint;
    metaExtensions: DoughnutMetaExtensions;
    parsedDataType: number;
    scales: keyof CartesianScaleTypeRegistry;
  };
```

cutout is in the chartoptions but

```
public doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    doughnut: {
      datasets: {
       /can't access cutout here /
      }
    }
...
};
```

but not sure how to access chartOptions. I am using the most recent version of ng2-charts and chart.js
chart.js@4.0.1
ng2-charts@4.1.1
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I was able to solve this by doing the following
`import { Chart } from 'chart.js'
Chart.overrides.pie.cutout = '50%'`

Answer (score 0):

Add chart type to options to map correctly:

```
public doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options'] = {
    cutout: '50%', // percentage of chart to cut out of the middle
    //cutout: 100, // pixels
...
};
```